# Issues with playing audio over voice channel; audio is truncated and each file is progressively more delayed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The end goal: I'm creating a discord bot built for Final Fantasy XIV raiding. You simply tell the bot when you pull the boss and it follows a pre-defined timeline that warns everyone of each mechanic shortly before it happens. In short: It plays a pre-defined list of audio files at pre-defined times after receiving a !start command.

The good news is that the audio is playing.

The bad news is...complicated.

There are two issues and I have a feeling they're related. The first issue is that, no matter what audio file I play, the last bit (about 0.5s) gets cut off. I gave it an audio file that says "Tank buster soon" and it played "Tank buster s-" then cut out. Up until now, I've been working around this by simply adding one second of silence on the end of every sound file. It's been working. It's still getting truncated, of course, it's just that it's truncating silence.

The second issue is that, after playing one audio file, the next audio file has a short delay between when the bot tries to start playing it, and when the audio actually comes out. (In discord, I can see this as the bot cueing up their "mic" a short time before it starts playing audio.) This delay gets progressively worse with every file played, to the point where it's literally several seconds delayed. (When the delay is severe enough, I see the bot cue up for about a second, un-cue, and then re-cue when the delay finally finishes)

The code doing most of the work is as follows:

```
//timeline() is called once per second by a setInterval() object, while the fight is active.
function timeline()
{
    tick++;

    var len = callouts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (tick == callouts[i]["time"])
        {
            dispatcher[dispatcherIndex] = voiceConnection.playFile(callouts[i]["file"]);
            dispatcherIndex++;
            activeChannel.send(callouts[i]["message"]);                 
        }
    }
} //end timeline()
```

Discord.js documentation mentions that it prefers node-opus to be used for voice functionality, but that opusscript will also work. I cannot seem to install the former, so I am using the latter.

EDIT: I've found a workaround for now. The progressive delay is "reset" when the bot leaves and rejoins voice, so I've simply made it do so when it finishes playing an audio file. Strictly speaking, it works, but I'd still like a "proper" solution if possible.

Comment: Wich version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using a version of discord.js downloaded today. Looks to be 11.5.1. *Not* the master, as npm can't seem to find that. ('npm install discordjs/discord.js' keeps throwing an error that says "This is related to npm not being able to find a file."

Comment: `npm install discordjs/discord.js` will most likely need you to have `git` installed. ( Could prob seen above the message )

Comment: Installing git did, indeed, help install discord.js master successfully. I haven't toyed with it much yet, but it seems like opusscript doesn't want to play nice with the master branch. I'll probably look into it more later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing git (why the *heck* have I not installed git long ago?) ultimately turned out to be the correct catalyst. That, as mentioned, let me install discord.js master branch, which handles voice better. After a couple ffmpeg-related hiccups, I now have the bot playing complete audio files with no delay, with no workarounds required. Everything's working great now!